# SQL eliminate duplicate rows with timestamp?

Tags: mysql, odoo, psql

I have  an SQL query for contracts linked to a unit, I want to be able to only show the unit (cp.name) with the latest timestamp(aaa.create_date) currently I get duplicates for every record for example like 3 for a id but it needs to be 1 how can I go around achieving this?

here is an example of my dilema :

```
id| unit |  area   | area_uom | valuation | target_rent | cmunit_id |  end_date  | state |        create_date         | occ
upancy_status 
------+----------------------------+---------+----------+-----------+-------------+-----------+------------+-------+----------------------------+------------------
 7740 | SM-A-A-Base-034/A          |   238.0 | sqft     |     710.0 |       700.0 |      8337 |            | close | 2014-11-14 14:35:58.03235  | 
 7740 | SM-A-A-Base-034/A          |   238.0 | sqft     |     710.0 |       700.0 |      8337 |            | open  | 2015-01-14 14:59:44.935075 | 
 7740 | SM-A-A-Base-034/A          |   238.0 | sqft     |     710.0 |       700.0 |      8337 |            |       |                            | 
 7741 | SM-A-A-Base-034/B          |   238.0 | sqft     |     710.0 |       700.0 |      8338 |            | close | 2014-11-14 14:35:58.03235  | 
 7741 | SM-A-A-Base-034/B          |   238.0 | sqft     |     710.0 |       700.0 |      8338 |            | open  | 2015-01-14 14:59:44.935075 | 
 7741 | SM-A-A-Base-034/B          |   238.0 | sqft     |     710.0 |       700.0 |      8338 |            |       |                            | 
 7559 | SM-A-A-GF-029[A]           |   238.0 | sqft     |     410.0 |       700.0 |      8156 |            | close | 2014-11-14 14:35:58.03235  | 
 7559 | SM-A-A-GF-029[A]           |   238.0 | sqft     |     410.0 |       700.0 |      8156 |            | open  | 2015-01-14 14:59:44.935075 | 
 7559 | SM-A-A-GF-029[A]           |   238.0 | sqft     |     410.0 |       700.0 |      8156 |            |       |               



select 
DISTINCT cp.id, 
cp.name as unit,
cp.area as area ,
cp.area_uom as area_uom,
cp.lettable  as lettable,
cp.valuation as valuation,
cp.target_rent as target_rent,
pt.company_id as company_id,
cta.cmunit_id,
aaa.date as end_date ,
aaa.state as state ,
aaa.create_date,
(case --- case is the  SQL equivalent of IF Statement ,  the statement will determine occupancy status based  on the end date , state of contract
when cp.lettable is false then 'not lettable'
when aaa.date <= NOW() then 'vacant'
when aaa.date > NOW()  then 'occupied'
end) as occupancy_status ,
pt.categ_id  as categ_id
from cm_property cp 

left outer join product_template pt
on cp.product_template_id = pt.id
left outer join cm_tenancy_account cta
on cta.cmunit_id = pt.id
left outer JOIN account_analytic_account aaa 
on  cta.cmtenant_id = aaa.id

where cp.name  LIKE '%SM-%' 

Order by cp.name
```

Comment: `select distinct` applies to ALL fields in the query. it's `select distinct(field1, field2,...)`, and not the equivalent of `select distinct(field1), field2, ...`

Answer (score 0):

Add `GROUP BY cp.id` to the end of your query.

Comment: I added the group by cp.id but it prompted me to add more columns to it , when i added more to the group by , the duplicates were still there